# Jquery Validate Plugin Prevent Double Submit On Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using a jquery validation plugin at:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I want to disabled submit button ONLY when validation passes:

It tried

```
$("#submit").click(function()
{
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

But this disables the submit button even if validation fails. Is there a way to only disable the submit when validation passes and a submit event occurs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking through the source, it *looks* like you should be able to override the `invalidHandler`, something along the lines of:

```
$("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    // disable your button here
    form.submit();
   },
   invalidHandler: function() {
     // re-enable the button here as validation has failed
   }
});
```

At a glance, this seems to be the way you'd want to go about doing this with the `validate` plugin, but I unfortunately don't have time atm to fiddle it to make *sure* it works.

**Edit:**

This should do 'er (I used a single text field with the name `fname` for testing):

```
$('#frm').bind('invalid-form.validate', function(){
    // you can add extra validation handling here if you want to
});

$('#frm').validate({
    rules: {
        fname: "required"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        $('form input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

`submitHandler` is *only* hit once validation has passed.

Comment: I tried, the form element disables but the form doesn't submit. Any other ideas?

Comment: still the same result. Any other ideas?

Comment: IT was because my input for submit was named submit. It is fixed now.

Comment: shouldn't form.submit() be f.submit() ?

Comment: it only worked because the browser's submit event was not prevented. there would still be an exception because `form` was undefined.